# What is the integral of AGM(1,x)dx

Tags: integration

I think it would involve u-substitution, but I do not know the derivative of AGM(1,x) or any AGM function, so no idea how to solve this problem. Please tell me the answer and your steps of how it is unsolvable and your steps. AGM is the arithmetic geometric mean function. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Arithmetic-GeometricMean.html.

Comment: Could you kindly tell us what AGM(1,x) is?

Comment: AGM is the arithmethic geometric mean function.

Comment: Is $x$ constrained?  For instance, $x > 0$...

Comment: It would be more clearly if you post explicit what you want to calculate. Just a kind advice.

Comment: @EricTowers I would prefer an answer that works for all x but if you have an answer that works for some x please tell me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a well-known theorem of Gauss that 
$$  \mathrm{AGM}(a,b) \int_0^{\infty}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{(x^2 + a^2)^{1/2} (x^2 + b^2)^{1/2}} = \frac{\pi}{2} \text{.}  $$
By simple substitution, 
$$  \mathrm{AGM}(a,b) \int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\mathrm{d}\theta}{(a^2 \cos^2 \theta + b^2 \sin^2 \theta)^{1/2}} = \frac{\pi}{2} \text{.}  $$

It is then straightforward that 
$$  \int \mathrm{AGM}(1,x) \, \mathrm{d}x = \frac{\pi}{2} \int \; \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\mathrm{d}\theta}{(\cos^2 \theta + x^2 \sin^2 \theta)^{1/2}}}  $$
and after recognizing the [complete elliptic integral of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Notational_variants) in the denominator, 
$$  \int \mathrm{AGM}(1,x) \, \mathrm{d}x = \frac{\pi}{2} \int \frac{x \,\mathrm{d}x}{K(1 - 1/x^2)}  \text{.}  $$

I would be shocked if this integral admits further simplification.

For more, read Cox, D. A., "Gauss and the Arithmetic-Geometric Mean", https://ctnt-summer.math.uconn.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/1632/2016/02/coxctnt.pdf .